# A matrix equation is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis

Consider the recursively defined sequence $\{x_k\}\subset\Bbb{R}^n:x_1,b\in\Bbb{R}^n$ are given, $x_{k+1}=Ax_k+b$ for $k\ge1,A=(a_{ij})$ a given $n\times n$ matrix with $\|A\|_F=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2}<1$

a) Show that $\{x_k\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence converges to some $x^*\in\Bbb{R}^n$

b) Show that $x^*=Ax^*+b$

c) Show that $x^*$ is the only solution to $x=Ax+b$

Comment: d). Show your work so far, so that we can help you?

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin... If I look at $\|x_n-x_m\|$ I get $\|Ax_{n-1}-Ax_{m-1}\|$ which doesn't really help me.  Should I be proving by induction?

Answer (score 1):

I shall show (a). (b) and (c) are immediate.

You may know that
$$\|Ax\|_2 \le \|A\|_F \|x\|_2$$
for a matrix $A$ and a vector $x$. By induction you can check that
$$x_n = (I+A+\cdots + A^{n-1})b + A^n x_1.$$

Since $\|A\|_F<1$, 
$$\|(I-A)x\|_2\ge \|x\|_2 - \|Ax\|_2 \ge (1-\|A\|_F)\|x||_2 > 0$$
for all nonzero $x$, so $I-A$ is invertible. From geometric series you may guess that $I+A+A^2+\cdots$ converges to $(I-A)^{-1}$. That is correct, and we shall use that guess.

We shall evaluate $\|x_n - (I-A)^{-1}b\|_2$. Applying induction to $(I-A)^{-1} = I + A(I-A)^{-1}$ gives
$$(I-A)^{-1} = I+A+A^2+\cdots + A^n + A^{n+1} (I-A)^{-1}$$
for all $n$. From this we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\|x_n - (I-A)^{-1}b\|_2 & = \|(I+A+\cdots A^{n-1})b + A^nx_1 - (I-A)^{-1}b\|
\\ &= \|(A^n(I-A)^{-1}b+ A^nx_1\|_2
\\ &\le \|A\|_F^{n+1}\|(I-A)^{-1}\|_F\|b\|_2 + \|A\|^n_F \|x_1\!\|_2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\|A\|_F<1$, RHS converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus $x_n$ converges to $x^* = (I-A)^{-1}b$.